# Office 2016 blocks document permanently after PC crashed

Tags: windows-10, smb, synology, microsoft-office-2016

I have recently upgraded from Office 2007 to Office 2016, and ever since then I observe the following behaviour:

I open a document from my Synology DS216J NAS mounted as UNC-Path via SMB for example in Excel for modification. The PC crashes for some reason, and needs to be rebooted without the possibility of closing Excel in advance. After the reboot, I try to open the document again. However, Excel displays a dialog telling that the document is currently in use. In Windows explorer, on that moutned drive, I see the original Office-document (test1.xlsx), and a hidden file (~$test1.xlsx), which both cannot be deleted in Windows explorer.

The strange thing is: I cannot delete these two files even if all office processes are closed. Even if I shutdown this PC, start another PC in the same network, these two files are blocked and not deletable.

My current workaround is to access my NAS logging in to the NAS directly and deleting the files from there, which works. Another thing I noticed that deleting the ~?-file is not suficient, I need to delete both files, before make a copy of the original file and rename after deletion.

My question is simple: who is blocking that file after a PC has crashed, even if Windows is restarted, or the file is being accessed from another PC, with the previously locking PC not even running? Is this a new Office feature (using NTFS alternate datastream or something similar)? Or is it a problem of my NAS' SMB implementation?

Finally, what is the suggested way to deal with that kind of deadlock-situation?

Comment: Sound like a problem of the NAS

Comment: _"these two files are blocked and not deletable"_ -- what does this mean? That's the error? Also, why can't you just disregard the "file is in use" warning?

Comment: @ivan: that means, Windows explorer cannot delete or rename these files, because they are locked, and Excel itself cannot save that file either. The only thing I could do is copy the files to another location and editing them there, which is not the desired solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, your NAS still has the (stale) connection to the crashed host and marks the files as open via it.

You need to somehow make it drop the connection and/or adjust its settings so that it detects and drops a stale connection itself within a reasonable time.

Rebooting the NAS is the simplest (but temporary) way.